# Generate random variable from series of its expected values E[X], E[X^2], E[X^3], ...?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Given a series of all the expected values of a random variable, can we find the random variable itself ?

Comment: These are usually called the moments about $0$

Comment: It depends: for example the distribution is determined (except on a set of measure $0$) if the moments are those of a normal distribution but not if they are the moments of a log-normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]$. Then:
$$i^n\,\mathbb{E}[X^n] = \varphi^{(n)}(0)$$
hence the problem of finding the distribution of $X$ given its moments is equivalent to finding an inverse Fourier transform for the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) $\varphi(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find the random variable itself, but you may be able to find its distribution.  Look up "moment generating function" or "characteristic function".

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_1 = 1_{[0,{1 \over 2})}$, $x_2 = 1_{[{1 \over 2},1]}$ on $[0,1]$. Then
$E[x_1^k] = E[x_2^k] = {1 \over 2}$ for all $k$, but clearly $x_1 \neq x_2$.